# NSTextField Line Spacing in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

How do you set the line-spacing for a multi-line NSTextField programmatically with Swift or within the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString` to modify this (Swift 4 example):

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10.0  // sets the space BETWEEN lines to 10 points
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 12.0 // sets the MAXIMUM height of the lines to 12 points

    let text = "Your text"
    let attributes = [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
    textField.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this approach breaks when the NSTextField is selectable. As the user selects the text, the field resets its attributes (probably) therefore making the text jump upwards with the default line spacing. Any ideas how to overcome this?